# How to make Python object behave like a numpy array?

Tags: c, python-2.7, numpy, ctypes

I'm developing a python 2.7 module, that runs compiled function from a dynamic library using `ctypes`. It contains a class that wraps a C structure from that library, representing an image, and is used to receive data from the C code.

Dynamic library performs deep copy of data, specially for python wrapper.

Further processing in the module is done using `numpy` arrays, therefore, I should convert data, retrieved from the C code, to `numpy.ndarray`.

Speed and memory consumption is not an issue for now.

For now, I've implemented a method in that class, that creates and returns `numpy.ndarray` using `numpy.frombuffer` function.

I'm wondering, if it can be implemented better.

Here is the python class

```
import ctypes as ct
import numpy as np

class C_Mat(ct.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("rows", ct.c_int),
                ("cols", ct.c_int),
                ("data", ct.c_char_p),
                ("step", ct.ARRAY(ct.c_int64, 2)),
                ("data_type", ct.c_int)]

    _dtypes = { 0: np.uint8,
                1: np.int8,
                2: np.uint16,
                3: np.int16,
                4: np.int32,
                5: np.float32,
                6: np.float64 }


    def image(self):
        r = np.frombuffer(self.data,
                          dtype=self._dtypes[self.data_type], 
                          count=self.cols*self.step[1]*self.step[0])
        r.shape = (self.cols, self.rows)
        r.strides = (self.step[0], self.step[1])

        return r
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the Array Interface description
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.interface.html